# How to use attach with two tables and two connect in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 8x, and i have two connections:

In `.env` :

```
DB_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx
DB_PORT=xxxx
DB_DATABASE=product
DB_USERNAME=product_sp
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx

DB_HOST_PROMOTION=xx.xx.xx.xx
DB_PORT_PROMOTION=xxx
DB_DATABASE_PROMOTION=product_sand
DB_USERNAME_PROMOTION=product_sp
DB_PASSWORD_PROMOTION=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

In model:

`Product.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'product';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public function discount()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Discount::class, 'product_discount',  'productId', 'discountId')->withPivot(['id','status', 'quantity', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'createdBy','updatedBy']);
    }
}
```

`discount.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
class Discount extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'discount';
    protected $connection = 'promotion';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

The `product_discount` table is an intermediate table of `discount` and `product`.

In the controller, I use `attach`

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $req = $request->all();
    $product = new Product($req);
    $extraFieldPivot = [
        'id' => (string) Str::uuid(),
        'status' => 1,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'createdAt' => now(),
        'updatedAt' => now(),
    ];
    $product->discount()->attach($req['idDiscount'], $extraFieldPivot)
}
```

But when I check the data. The result has not been saved to the database. So where did I go wrong, please advise me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i think your intermediate table needs to be changed like productId to product_id and discountId to discount_id.

and change your relationship according to your change in table

If your model relationship is correct change your store function to

```
$public function store(Request $request) 
{
$req = $request->all();
$product = Product::create($req);
$extraFieldPivot = [
    'id' => (string) Str::uuid(),
    'status' => 1,
    'quantity' => 1,
    'createdAt' => now(),
    'updatedAt' => now(),
];
$product->discount()->attach($product, $extraFieldPivot)
}
```